# What does the '@>' mean in this Postgres sql snippet?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postrgres sql snippet I copied and it is working but I don't understand what '@>' in the where clause is doing, and can't seem to find a reference.

```
select 
    my_column
from 
    my_table
where 
    earth_box( ll_to_earth(my_lat, my_lng), 2000) @> ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude);
```

The snippet is coming from [here](http://johanndutoit.net/searching-in-a-radius-using-postgres/).

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it basically means "contains"...so the geom returned from the earth_box function must contain the geom returned from the ll_to_earth function.
A horse with no name's link has the list of them all.

Until now I've only ever seen just @ alone, but apparently this @> means contains.

Answer (score 0):

see the reference "Geometric Functions and Operators" at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-geometry.html